# Awk-- splitting a string into sub-strings with length n

Tags: awk

I am familiar with function split() which is used in awk programs. I was wondering how I can use it to split a string into smaller strings with length of n? Something like (n is set at 2):

input:

```
abcdefgh
```

output:

```
ab cd ef gh
```

Comment: Are you asking for a `split()` solution because for some reason you NEED a `split()` solution or because that's what you THINK splitting a string into substrings will involve? There are several alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `gawk` you can also do:

```
$ echo 'abcdefgh' | awk -F '' '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) {printf "%s%s ", $i,$(i+1);}}'
ab cd ef gh
```

From gawk [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Field-Splitting-Summary.html):

> FS == ""
>
> Each individual character in the record becomes a separate
> field. (This is a gawk extension; it is not specified by the POSIX
> standard.)

Comment: I believe this is gawk specific, just for the record.

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes, behavior of `awk` on using empty `FS` to split is undefined in POSIX.

Answer (score 20):

Since you accepted a non-split() solution, here's one that's non-gawk-specific, briefer, and probably faster :-):

```
$ awk '{gsub(/.{2}/,"& ")}1' file
ab cd ef gh

$ awk '{gsub(/.{3}/,"& ")}1' file
abc def gh
```

Just like the loop-based one you accepted, it adds a trailing blank char when the input string is an exact multiple of the number of chars you want it split on.

Comment: +1 .. this scales so much better than the accepted answer; if you wanted to split a string into 50 or 100 length segments for example.

Comment: Additionally, if you wanted to split a long line into fixed length line segments - like a single line of `base64` for example, just change `{2}` to `{64}` and substitute `"& "` with `"&\n"` - Handy for reformatting those mangled SSH or GPG keys, just remember to strip the literal `\n` characters first!

Comment: Thanks. may I know what does the tailing "1" stand for? I can change it to other numbers like 2, 3, but it fails if I remove it.

Comment: @lesca See https://www.google.com/search?q=what+does+1+do+at+the+end+of+an+awk+script. The first result from that is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63891/what-is-the-meaning-of-1-at-the-end-of-an-awk-script.

Answer (score 4):

Split function in `(g)awk` is meant to split a string on delimiters. It populates an array with fields that are delimited by the delimiter. Since your string has none and you basically want to split the string in chunks, you can use GNU `awk` feature of `split` which also creates an optional array based on separator.

```
gawk 'BEGIN {
    n = split ("abcdefgh", ary, /../, seps);
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) 
       printf "%s%s", seps[i], (i<n?FS:RS)
}'
ab cd ef gh
```

Comment: Man. I keep missing out on all the cool stuff because my day-to-day work is on CentOS 5 with its older versions of things. =)

Comment: @EtanReisner I hear you. I work on RHEL6 and miss out them too. I was going to suggest `perl -MData::Dumper -ne'@ary = /(..)/g }{ print Dumper \@ary' <<< "abcdefgh"` but then realized I was home and had latest version handy! `:)`

Answer (score 2):

If you can come up with a delimiter that does not appear in the string then an approach like this will work:

```
awk 'BEGIN {f="abcdefgh"; gsub(/../, "& ", f); split(f, a, FS); print a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4]}'
```

Comment: You can usually use RS as the delimiter that can't appear in the string. Since the input was split into records at each occurrence of an RS, there can't be an RS in the record. Gets trickier with multi-char RSs though.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
echo "abcdefgh" | awk 'BEGIN {ORS=" "}{for (i=1;i<=length($0);i+=2) print substr( $0, i, 2 )}'
```